# Need help for Mysql database connect in web.config in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

When I try to connect my MySql Database in web.config and create object in my class file it give me server error. My Connection string is bellow.

```
<add name="MyConn" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="Server=localhost;User ID=root;Password=demo@123;Database=pay2school;port=3306;pooling=false;respect binary flags=false"/>
```

My Cs code is below

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();
    string datacon;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

  datacon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConn"].ToString();
conn = new MySqlConnection(datacon);
//conn.ConnectionString = datacon;
  //  conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConn"].ConnectionString);
    Response.Write(conn);
}
```

I got error is below

> Server Error in '/WebSite1' Application. Keyword not supported.
>   Parameter name: respect binary flags Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported.
>   Parameter name: respect binary flags
>
> Source Error:

```
   Line 20: 
    Line 21:       datacon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConn"].ToString();
    Line 22:     conn = new MySqlConnection(datacon);
    Line 23:     //conn.ConnectionString = datacon;
    Line 24:       //  conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConn"].ConnectionString);
```

Please Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you actually need that parameter?  Could you take it out?  i.e. change connection string to

```
<add name="MyConn" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="Server=localhost;User ID=root;Password=demo@123;Database=pay2school;port=3306;pooling=false;"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply dear. Yes I relay need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConn"].ConnectionString`